# Edição aprovada, não acrescenta nada a pergunta

Tags: debate, edições-sugeridas

Já sei que já andamos nisto a séculos, mas o que traz de bom esta edição?

Nada, acho que até está muito pior a nova que a antiga.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/25415/revisions

Agora aprova-se tudo só porque sim? O que fazer num caso destes? Eu apetecia-me logo reverter, mas como acho que ia dar confusão abri aqui no meta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não me parece exatamente pior que a antiga, mas realmente não vejo muita diferença na leitura e algumas partes que poderiam ter sido melhoradas não o foram, como o `PHP`. Se eu visse isso na fila provavelmente teria reeditado ou rejeitado.

Comment: Eu `acho` pior @utluiz porque, `imaginando` que é uma `pergunta` relativamente `longa`, se `vamos` por a `tag de código` em `tudo` estamos `tramados`.

Comment: Nossa! Na verdade não havia reparado nas tags de código!!! Tem é que reverter isso...

Comment: Acredito que a opção correta seria rejeitar pelo motivo: "A edição é insuficiente; sugestões de edição precisam melhorar significativamente a postagem, resolvendo os diversos problemas que ela apresentar."

Comment: Tópico similar: [Editar/alterar conteúdo da resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1700/3117)

Comment: @Math mas já tinha sido aprovada quando estava a rejeitar. A pergunta é mesmo essa o que fazer sendo que foi aprovada?

Comment: @JorgeB. essa sua pergunta é mais complexa, por isso mesmo eu pus um comentário e não uma resposta, rsrs.. Eu tb gostaria de saber o que fazer, vamos esperar para ver o que os outros têm a dizer.

Comment: A parte ortográfica ficou melhor, mas tirando isso, não foi modificado nada muito relevante.

Comment: Opinião pessoal, não vi necessidade nem mesmo em editar. Como já comentaram, a nova edição ficou na mesma, só que de um jeito um pouco diferente e mais um detalhe é que repetiu um mesmo erro do original, por exemplo, no trecho "á parte?", a letra "a" não leva acento.